# Differences in OpenCV image matrix after re-saving as PNG, despite matching dependencies

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with a colleague, and we both have identical Ubuntu installations (actually, same docker images) with the same packages and dependencies. We decided to investigate a peculiar behavior when working with OpenCV-Python. We both took the same JPEG image file (we verified using `md5sum` that the files are equal) and opened it using OpenCV, but to our surprise, we observed differences in the resulting image matrix.

To test this further, we used `cv2.imwrite` to re-save the image as a PNG file and compared the resulting PNG files using `md5sum`. Interestingly, the checksums were different despite our matching configurations.

We double checked that we have the same versions of:

Ubuntu
OpenCV
Python
libjpeg
libpng

We would like to understand the reason behind this behavior and what could be causing these differences in the resulting PNG images.

Is there any specific configuration or parameter that we might be overlooking when using OpenCV to save images as PNG? Any insights or suggestions on why the saved PNG files differ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might try running `cv2.getBuildInformation()` on the two machines and diffing the results.

Comment: Drop the whole PNG part, that's not really adding anything, just muddying the water (if the numpy arrays already differ, further encoding won't change things). Focus on the different decoding of JPEGs by `imread`. Does this happen for every image? Are there any hardware differences? What are the exact versions of everything that's invoved here? How big are the actual differences, how many?